# Active Storage on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activestorage

all. Has anyone had success deploying previewable Active Storage on Heroku. I followed the [guidance on the Heroku Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku#attachment-previews), added the buildpack, but still no love. When running `which ffmeg` or `which poppler` from heroku bash, I get no response which indicates that the necessary binaries did not get installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you deploy again after adding the binaries?

Comment: Yes, I subsequently deployed. The app shows the buildpack as installed.